# How could I add a parameter to this function to set the depth of the minimum?

Tags: functions

I have the equation $y = -e^{0.03(p - x - e^{p - x})} + b$ defined with the following parameters:

- $b$: baseline vertical offset
- $p$: peak horizontal offset

I want to change the equation such that another parameter can be added that controls the depth of the peak. How could this be done?

[image]

In Python, this can be represented as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 300, 0.01)

peak_offset_horizontal   = 40 # the horizontal offset of the peak from 0
baseline_offset_vertical = 0 # the vertical offset of the (flat) baseline from 0
y = - np.exp(0.03 * (peak_offset_horizontal - x - np.exp(peak_offset_horizontal - x))) + baseline_offset_vertical
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more about writing code than about mathematics.

Comment: @quid Why might you think this? The equation is shown clearly at the `y = ...` line and the question is mathematics-related, not code-related. The code is shown to add context: I've got multiple parameters and I'm trying to add another.

Comment: @quid I have taken the equation outside of the body of code. Hopefully that makes it clearer and illustrates that this is explicitly *not* a code question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications, I can see the mathematical aspect now.